# Spacemacs menu in mini-buffer displays Dired+ "C-x D A" command unreliably

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, dired, menus

Two weeks ago I installed [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus).

I successfully used Dired+ `C-x D A` (diredp-add-to-dired-buffer) command.
But the Dired+ `C-x D A` command is not always available.
Sometimes after `C-x`, the `D` appears in the Spacemacs menu, in the minibuffer, like this:

```
D -> +prefix
```

Other times `D` is missing from the Spacemacs menu.
Although the Dired+ help displays as expected:

```
SPC SPC diredp-dired-plus-help
```

The inclusion of `D` in the menu seems random.

Also, when `C-x D A` is not available, it is not found in `SPC h d k`.

However, `M-x diredp-add-to-dired-buffer` works as expected.

I tried rebooting.

Like Drew said, maybe some other package I use might be grabbing the key binding.  I haven't checked that yet.

Maybe I installed Dired+ the wrong way.
My `.spacemacs` file contains `dired+` twice:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/layers ()
  (setq-default
..
   dotspacemacs-additional-packages '(dired+)
)
..
(custom-set-variables
 '(package-selected-packages
   (quote
    (disaster dired+
```

What else could be causing the intermittent spacemacs-menu behavior?

I contacted the author of Dired+, but he doesn't know Spacemacs.

I am using Emacs 25.2.1 with Evil Spacemacs and Ivy on Linux.

Comment: Do you mean `C-x D S` instead of `C-x D A`? The former is command `diredp-fileset`. The latter is command `diredp-add-to-dired-buffer`.

Comment: It sounds like some other package you use might be grabbing the key binding you are trying to use (sometimes: when that keymap is active). Have you tried binding the command you want (e.g. `diredp-fileset`) to some other key, to see if the problem is related to the original key or to the command?

Comment: @Drew, I meant  C-x D A (diredp-add-to-dired-buffer), I just didn't know the name of the function.
M-x diredp-add-to-dired-buffer works as expected.
Thanks for giving me the name of the function :)
So I will use "M-x diredp-add-to-dired-buffer" until I learn how to bind commands to keys.

Comment: `(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd <SOME KEY YOU WANT>) 'diredp-add-to-dired-buffer)`